# How to make a game autosave and autoload

Tags: python, game-engine, properties, logic-bricks

I need my game to always save all settings and scores, also always load them when running game. And... I want to also save theese objects, which has disappeared from scenes(collected points, boost ups, etc.) Who can help me, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's probably a much easier way, but you could have variables which change depending on what level your in ect, along with others that toggle the use of boost ups and collected points etc. Then you can save these variables to different .txt files so that they're the same when you start up the game next time.

#### For Python Variables:

Connect this script to a keyboard sensor, with a status of All Keys, followed by an always sensor. The pytho controller is in module mode. You need a folder next to the .blend called "SaveLoad". And finally add two game properties to you object just so that you can see that the script really works.

S Key to save, L Key to Load and A Key to change the variables, but obviously you can easily modify the code to you needs of automatic execution.

```
import bge
from bge import logic
path = logic.expandPath("//SaveLoad/")

cont = logic.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner
keys = cont.sensors["Keyboard"]

var1 = 20
var2 = 60

def save():
    global var1
    global var2
    for key,status in keys.events:
        if status == logic.KX_INPUT_JUST_ACTIVATED:
            string = bge.events.EventToString(key)
            
            if string == "SKEY":
                info = str(var1)+","+str(var2)
                file = open(path+str(own)+".txt", "w")
                file.write(str(info))
            
            if string == "LKEY":
                file = open(path+str(own)+".txt", "r")
                line = file.readline().replace("\n","").split(",")
                var1 = int(line[0])
                var2 = int(line[1])
            
            if string == "AKEY":
                var1 += 1
                var2 += 2
    
    own["prop"] = var1
    own["prop0"] = var2
```

#### For Game Properties

This script needs to be set up the same way as the variable script, but yet again you do have the option to change it to your needs.

```
from bge import logic
path = logic.expandPath("//SaveLoad/")

cont = logic.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner
keys = cont.sensors["Keyboard"]

### Use keyboard
for key,status in keys.events:
    if status == logic.KX_INPUT_JUST_ACTIVATED:
        string = bge.events.EventToString(key)
        
        ### Save "prop" and "prop0" to file
        if string == "SKEY":
            info = str(own["prop"])+","+str(own["prop0"])
            file = open(path+str(own)+".txt", "w")
            file.write(str(info))
        
        ### Load "prop" and "prop0" from file
        if string == "LKEY":
            file = open(path+str(own)+".txt", "r")
            line = file.readline().replace("\n","").split(",")
            own["prop"] = int(line[0])
            own["prop0"] = int(line[1])
        
        ### Change values
        if string == "AKEY":
            own["prop"] += 1
            own["prop0"] += 1.3
```

Comment: Will it save in the same folder as .exe when I make game runtime? Will it use .exe file's directory/SaveLoad/?

Comment: It worked, thank's! Now I will just have to figure out the principals on gamesave.

Comment: Is it possible to do it infinite like this: info = str(own[])+","+str(own[])+","+str(own[])?

Comment: file = open(path+str(own)+".txt", "w")- does it save the game as object_on_which_is_added_python_controller_name.txt?

Comment: Hi! This is important! How do I replace LKEY with always? What should I place in "LKEY" place for always actuator?

Comment: Please, tell me how do I make it always save and load, not only then, when I use buttons. I need my game to always save and load settings(best way, evry second frame)

Comment: I tried to change properties in game, I changed some data. Than I tried it out. It saved my data, but I could not load. I checked the directory I use, .txt file was there with all contents. Why it does not work? I used 1 integer and 3 floaters, but I changed `own["prop"] = int(line[1])` to `own["prop"] = float(line[1])`

Comment: About the always thing - instead of buttons - add an always sensor and add it as well to the python controller. Then, underneath the keys variable, add__   always = own.sensors["Always"]    __and replace the LKEY, etc - which ever buttons you plan to make always - if statements into always.positive      so   if string == "LKEY":    becomes    if always.positive == True: